# Pull a character from a long string and make only character linkable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a text that contains something like this, "Need more information? See our notes". This text comes from a database column. I can find '?', but I can't set '?' to be linkable only using Rails link_to. Here is the code:

```
text = "Need more information? See our notes" # THIS TEXT COMES FROM THE DATABASE
```

```
- if /[?]/.match(text)
    %h2
      = link_to anchor: 'lead' do
        = text
```

Any thoughts will be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want `?` to be a link?

Comment: Yes Vimsha, I meant '?' to be linkable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one should do the thing:

```
- if /[?]/.match(text)
    %h2
      != text.sub('?', link_to('?', anchor: 'lead'))
```